# Ошибка при запуске бота node.js вк

Tags: node.js

Вот код:

```
const { VK } = require('vk-io')
const request = require('prequest');

const commands = []

const vk = new VK();

vk.setOptions({
    token: 'тут мой токен',
    pollingGroupId: тут айди группы,
    app: тут ид приложения,
    key: 'тут ключ приложения',
    phone: 'тут мой телефон'
})

const auth = vk.auth.standalone();

auth.run()
.then((token) => {
    console.log('User token:',token);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'callbackService')

Comment: Т. е. надо угадать, где происходит обращение к свойству, которого у тебя в приведённом коде вообще нет? Если уж это не в твоём коде, то хоть стек покажи полностью.

Comment: это полностью весь код